# Using jna lib to write to registry throws either access is denied or System cannot find the file specified(lib not loaded)

Tags: java, netbeans, permissions, registry, jna

So i have application that needs to use JNA lib to write to registry, when i want to run it from netbeans i get **Access is denied** i guess i dont have permissions to write with `Advapi32Util.registrySetIntValue`

So i created batch file that run my application with administrator privileges and did same thing now i got **The system cannot find the file specified** when i get to `Advapi32Util.registrySetIntValue`

To see better here is a screen:
On the left you see my netbeans execution and on the right batc hfile execution with admin privileges.I do have lib folder filled with same libraries , **When you look at console of command promt you see VALUE READ:-1 , that means i cant even read with the library jna.platform.win32** Why is my library not loaded?

[image]

I use jnativehook that is in the folder **lib** and that one is loaded no problem , **netbeans execution also loaded jna.platform.win32** as you can see i coud read value 1 **instead of no value has been read -1**

I have no idea what is happening there must be something wrong, both libraries are in the same folder, same imports **its exactly the same .jar file beign coppied to test folder for jars**

**So question , why i get this result? Why is my lib not loaded when i can load library jnativehook that is in the same folder and use it normally bud jna throws error?Dont forget that everything loads well in netbeans , i just lack necessery privileges to run writing to registry(i can read from registry with no problem).**

Additional not so important code information:

Imports:

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg;
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
```

Reading method:

```
  public static final int readFromLEProperties(String guid) {

        System.out.println("GUID IS:" + guid);

        try {
            int valueInReg = Advapi32Util.registryGetIntValue(

                    WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\MMDevices\\"
                    + "Audio\\Render\\" + guid + "\\FxProperties", "{E0A941A0-88A2-4df5-8D6B-DD20BB06E8FB},4");
            System.out.printf("LE Value: %s\n", valueInReg);
            return valueInReg;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Coudnt read value from properties path:" + "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\MMDevices\\"
                    + "Audio\\Render\\" + guid + "\\FxProperties   NAME:" + "{E0A941A0-88A2-4df5-8D6B-DD20BB06E8FB},4");
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

And writing method:

```
 public static final void writeToLEProperties(String guid, boolean activateLE) {


        try{
              Advapi32Util.registrySetIntValue(WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\MMDevices\\"
                + "Audio\\Render\\" + guid + "\\FxProperties", "{E0A941A0-88A2-4df5-8D6B-DD20BB06E8FB},4", (activateLE) ? 1 : 0);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error: AD");
        }
}
```

Comment: Compare your classpath and system properties between the two different invocations.  Chances are something within those is different.

Comment: @technomage "and system properties""? now sure what you mean coud you elaborate and tell me how to do it? Hope its something little like that cause i really cant crack whats going on

Comment: [`System.getProperties()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/system_getproperties.htm).